# Create multiple hyperlinks in single cell of JQGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, jqgrid

I am developing an MVC4 application which has also nice client side interaction. But today,I got a specific requirement that there can be dynamic number of links in a cell of jqGrid. The approach I am taking is :

1. Create array of items in controller to be formatted as hyperlinks in jqGrid
2. Get this array as JQGrid cell value and iterate for each r=array item to format it as hyperlink
3. Call controller method for each hyperlink

Controller piece for jqGrid:

```
  var jsonData =new {rows = (from row in dlist
                                           select new {
                                                         Id = row.ContactOrderNo,
                                                         cell = new string[] {
                                                         Convert.ToString(row.ContactOrderNo)
                                                        ,Convert.ToString(row.ContactOrderNo)
                                                        ,Convert.ToString(row.SerialNumber)
                                                        ,Convert.ToString(row.ModelNo)
                                                        ,Convert.ToString(row.Capacity)
                                                        ,Convert.ToString(new Obj[]{ new {LinkText="22.pdf", LinkSrc="mydrive\\22.pdf"}, new {LinkText="33.pdf", LinkSrc="mydrive\\33.pdf"})        
                                                        }                                               

                                           }).ToArray()
                               };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

JQGrid Script :

```
colNames: ['Contract-OrderNum', 'Contract Order Number', 'Serial Number', 'Model Number', 'Capacity', 'ContractDetails'],
    colModel: [
                    { name: 'ModelNo', width: 150, editable: false, hidden: true, editrules: { required: true } },
                    {
                        name: 'Contract-OrderNo', width: 300, editable: false, hidden: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                            return '<a href="/OrderList/AddOrder/?ModelNo=' + cellvalue + '" >' + cellvalue + '</a>';
                        }
                    },

                       { name: 'SerialNumber', width: 150, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                       { name: 'ModelNo', width: 150, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                        { name: 'Capacity', width: 150, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                          {
                              name: 'ContractDetails', width: 150, editable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                  return '<a href="/OrderList/GetPDFFileStream/?rowObject=' + rowObject + '" target="_blank" >' + cellvalue + '</a>';
                              }
                          }

    ],
```

Please advise me the workaround needed to achieve it.

Comment: First of all the Controller Action need generate the data which described the required information. For example if could be just array of items where every item like `new {ContactOrderNo=row.ContactOrderNo, SerialNumber=row.SerialNumber, ModelNo=row.ModelNo, Capacity=row.Capacity, ContractDetails=...}`. If the value of ContractDetails should describe multiple links then the value could be array (or List) of items with the properties `linkSrc`, `LinkText`. Such output from controller will describe the required information and the custom fotmatter will just convert the information to links.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your prompt reply ! Do you mean I need to send 'linkSrc', 'LinkText' from controller. In that case what and how should I get in custom-formatter.

Comment: I mean the values like `ContractDetails = new [] {new {LinkText="Google", linkSrc="http://www.google.com/"}, new {LinkText="Stackoverflow", linkSrc="http://stackoverflow.com/"}}`. It's better it you include two rows of test data which could generate controller and which would be describe the required information. jqGrid is able to read practical any format of data. So the controller just need to return array of items and every item should describe the row in any format.

Comment: Got that ! Then How will I parse it in JqGrid. There is a column        name: 'ContractDetails', width: 150, editable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                  return '<a href="/OrderList/GetPDFFileStream/?rowObject=' + rowObject + '" target="_blank" >' + cellvalue + '</a>';
                              }
Using your dynamiclink formatter how will I get those values? Please elaborate.

Comment: The code of the custom formatter depends on the exact format if the data generated by controller. The `cellvalue` in the formatter will rep represent the value of `ContractDetails` property in the input data and `rowObject` will be the full item of input data which represent the whole row. The custom formatter need just returns the string which is HTML fragment with links generated based on the input data. jqGrid will place the HTNL fragment in `<td>` (the cells) of the column. **It's better if you include two rows of test data in the text of your question.**

Comment: Yes Oleg I am aware of that. My concern is: When I will send 2 values from controller like you demonstrated in your previous comment, then how will I specify those values separately in a single cell as in that case 'cellvalue' will contain all 2 values and then I have to mark each value as hyperlink
I have edited the controller section in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multipleHiperlinks.htm) for you which demonstrates the corresponding custom formatter. In display the grid

[image]

from the input data

```json
[
    {"ContactOrderNo":123, "SerialNumber":"abc", "ModelNo":"ModelNo1", "Capacity":123456,
     "ContractDetails":[{"LinkText":"12.pdf", "LinkSrc":"http://www.glsh.net/media/files/Druckertest.pdf"}, {"LinkText":"13.pdf", "LinkSrc":"http://www.tinten-toner-24.com/shared/pdf/testseite.pdf"}]},
    {"ContactOrderNo":456, "SerialNumber":"xyz", "ModelNo":"ModelNo2", "Capacity":789012,
     "ContractDetails":[{"LinkText":"22.pdf", "LinkSrc":"http://www.glsh.net/media/files/Druckertest.pdf"}, {"LinkText":"23.pdf", "LinkSrc":"http://www.tinten-toner-24.com/shared/pdf/testseite.pdf"}]}
]
```

which should generate the server.

The definition of the `ContractDetails` column in the demo looks like below

```js
{ name: "ContractDetails",
    formatter: function (cellvalue) {
        var i, res = "", linkInfo;

        if (cellvalue == null || !$.isArray(cellvalue)) {
            return "&nbsp;"; // empty cell in case or error
        }

        for (i = 0; i < cellvalue.length; i++) {
            linkInfo = cellvalue[i];
            res += (res.length > 0 ? ", " : "") +
                '<a href="' + linkInfo.LinkSrc + '" target="_blank" >' +
                linkInfo.LinkText + '</a>';
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the cell value . when i use this function it sayscell value is undefined. can you please guide

Comment: @sandy143: `cellvalue` is the value from input data for the column (the property `ContractDetails` of input data in the case). You should post separate question with an example of your input data, which you use to fill the grid, the information about the version and the fork of jqGrid, which you use and to describe what results you want to have. Probably you don't need to use custom formatter at all and to use predefined formatter with the corresponding options.